# I need a command-line utility to send switch keyboard layout sequence because of Ubuntu 21.04 wayland

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, wayland, 21.04

For X11 I used to setxkbmap command to change keyboard layout.
Now on Ubuntu 21.04 I have wayland.
Does any command-line utility can send win+space key sequence to change keyboard layout?

Thanks.

Comment: <Super>+Space is the default shortcut on Ubuntu for changing keyboard layout. Why do you want a command for that?

Comment: Because I use my own shortcut. The shortcut is absent in Gnome Tweaks tool/ Keyboard  & Mouse/Additional Layout Options/Switching to another Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I use standart Gnome/Tweaks utility to choose

> Caps Lock to first layout;Shift+Caps Lock to last layout

in

> Keyboard & Mouse/Additional Layout Options/Switching to another layout.

Second, I've found and installed **evemu-tools** package in Ubuntu.
These two commands emulate CAPSLOCK pressed on keyboard (/dev/input/event6):

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_CAPSLOCK --value 1 --sync

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_CAPSLOCK --value 0 --sync

Another four commands emulate SHIFT+CAPSLOCK pressed on keyboard (/dev/input/event6):

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_RIGHTSHIFT --value 1 --sync

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_CAPSLOCK --value 1 --sync

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_CAPSLOCK --value 0 --sync

> sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event6 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_RIGHTSHIFT --value 0 --sync

P.S. I have added a new record to /etc/sudoers to permit evemu-event program do not ask password when used with sudo. Please, correct me if it's not good way to grant permissions to evemu-event.

Now I can use above commands sets to switch keyboard-layout in wayland.
I will search for an automation package to set change layout function to any keyboard keys.
Thanks.